# How to use Hash of a passphares to encrypt

Tags: java, hash, key, encryption

So basically.
I want to use a Hash of a passphrase to encrypt a masterkey.
For the moment code I used is this

```
try {
        //Conservazione delle chiavi!
        //Secure PRNG
        SecureRandom m = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        //Secure HASH
        MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        //KeyGenerator 
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
        keyGenerator.init(m);
        //Want to obtain a random masterkey that need to encrypt
        Key key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        //Get DES cipher
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
        //AND NOW?
                    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, KEY); // THAT's the problem.



    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The Key is the hash of my passphrase..
Something like hash.digest(passphrase.getBytes());
 where passpharse is a simple string.
any suggest to how use hash as key? 
I should init keyGenerator with the Hash of my passphrase?

Comment: Reading your question through the comments in your code is a little difficult. Can you phrase a clear question in the prose of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I resolved

```
SecureRandom m = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
//Secure Hash
MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
//get a KeyGenerator DES init with a PRNG
KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
keyGenerator.init(m);
//get Masterkey
Key masterkey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
//Get a DES cipger
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
//AND HERE HOW I RESOLVED!
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOf(hash.digest(passphrase.getBytes()), 8), "DES");
```

I've used SecretKeySpec to obtain my Key. But because my hash.digest(passphrase) is too long I had to copy only first 8 bytes (because DES key is 64bit long).

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is to use [`DESKeySpec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/DESKeySpec.html) and [`KeyFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.html) using an algorithm string `"DES"` for the `getInstance(String)` method (just like you do for your `KeyGenerator`. So you wrap the right amount of bytes from the front (leftmost) part of your byte array containing the hash, wrap it in a `DESKeySpec` and use the `SecretKeyFactory.generateSecret()` method to create a key from it.

Indirectly, you should not use `"DES"` anymore. Instead look into password based encryption, AES, CBC and key wrapping. Make sure you don't use the code above in a production environment before you upgrade.

Comment: I know it''s not secure anymore des protocol (probably triple des should be better) but I need just to understand mechanism behind symmetric cipher

Comment: @AntonioCalì DES is fine as a cipher used for practice. Note though that DES has a rather large set of peculiarities, such as DES parity bits. Because of this you cannot use a random (looking) block of bytes as key. That's why you should really use `SecretKeyFactory` here. AES is for instance fine with directly using `SecretKeySpec` as `SecretKey`. The parity bits also reduce the key space to 56 bits. In modern crypto we use AES not just because it is stronger but also faster and easier in use.